# What version of Evolution will be in Maverick?

Tags: 10.10, evolution

I've tried Evolution 2.30.3 from Jacob's ppa on Lucid and the version of 2.30.3 in Maverick beta, they differ and both have significant shortcomings. You can't right click on an email and create a meeting, event or task, for example. Some settings don't work in the Maverick version -- (un)compress weekends in month view, for example. No alarms for events just adds to its woes.

If evo is not working reliably in Maverick, I'll stick with 2.28.3 in Lucid.

Answer (score 3):

According to its Launchpad page the current version in Maverick is 2.30.3.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution

(Tip: You can use any package name in Ubuntu and replace it in that URL and find that information for any given package in the archive and any supported release.)

Answer (score 2):

According to [Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/evolution) it appears to be Evolution 2.30.3-1ubuntu3 Though as Maverick hasn't been released yet it may change - though unlikely as it's so close to release.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. The current daily build has Evolution 2.30.3-1ubuntu3, and http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/evolution has 2.30.3-1ubuntu4 as the version in freeze. I will try the latest and hope the issues have been solved.